# Multi Condition While Loop (w/ multiple conditions within same variable)

Tags: arrays, matlab, while-loop, iteration

Here's the basic setup.  I am trying to create a while loop that will iterate until a set condition is below a certain tolerance.  However, this loop must be generalized for multiple values within the same matrix.  An example (simplified from what I'm currently trying to accomplish):

```
x = [3; 2]
tolerance = [0,0]
iter = 0
while x > tolerance
x = x - 1;
iter = iter + 1;
end
```

The issue I am facing is that the while loop will exit as soon as 1 of the values in the function is less than the tolerance.  What I intend to occur is that the while loop will continue to iterate on both variables until both are below the desired tolerance.  I am unable to have two separate loops because the size of the variable I will be iterating upon is not set at 2 values.

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab has a couple of related functions, `any` and `all` that help with this kind of thing.

[any](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html), which returns `true` if any of the elements are truthy, will help you here:

```
while any(x>tolerance)
   ...
end
```

You can also do other tricks like

```
while sum(x>tolerance) > 0
```

to achieve the same thing, but I like how semantically clear `any` is.